# I don't believe my question is a duplicate. Anything I can do?

Tags: support, specific-question, exact-duplicates

My question here was deemed a duplicate but i don't agree that it is. The question is similar but the answers there didn't address my question.
Question that was closed:
[How can He reign over no subjects? [אדון עולם אשר מלך בטרם כל יצור נברא]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139910/how-can-he-reign-over-no-subjects-%d7%90%d7%93%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%9c%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%a9%d7%a8-%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%9a-%d7%91%d7%98%d7%a8%d7%9d-%d7%9b%d7%9c-%d7%99%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%a8-%d7%a0%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%90?noredirect=1#comment467327_139910)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that your question, which poses a particular difficulty, is distinct from the post it was duped to, which asks what a phrase means. So, I re-opened your post.

Here are some things you can do if you think a post should be re-opened:

- Vote to re-open it. (I'm not sure if you have this option on your own post.)
- Add comments explaining why you believe your question is distinct from the other question. Contrary to some comments, the content of answers doesn't determine whether question posts are duplicates; the content of the questions does. The *existence* of answers on the other post is a prerequisite for the community voting to close as a duplicate of it.
- Edit your post to make it clear (preferably organically to your question rather than as meta-commentary) how your post is distinct.
- Flag for moderator attention, with a note explaining how you believe your post is distinct.
- Write a Meta post like this one, explaining why you believe your post is distinct.